# Root folder rename in magento2

Tags: magento2

Proper way of changing the root folder name in Magento2?

I want to move the files from htdocs/Magento2x_1 to htdocs/Magento2x_2.

Answer (score 3):

You can change or move the root folder path as well as you need to go to Mysql table `core_config_data` and replace the base url paths by modified name.

Change the path value

For example

1. **Path** `web/unsecure/base_url` **value** `http://127.0.0.1/Magento2x_2 ( replaced by Magento2x_1. )`
2. **path** `web/secure/base_url` **value** `http://127.0.0.1/Magento2x_2 ( replaced by Magento2x_1. )`
3. Refresh the cache ( `php bin/magento cache:clean;` ) and load the application by new path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And what about Store->General->Web secure and unsecure urls? and after moving, any composer update?  Cause i tried the above before, i get Object not found error

Comment: You can find or modify the information in core_config_data table "web/secure/use_in_frontend"  for secure and un-secure. and run setup-upgrade command.